# how to select the value of oi-select in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am writing a script to automate my form submission. Using webdriver code I am able to add the data to all html inputs except `oi-select`.

My HTML DOM:

```
<oi-select class="multiSelect ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required multiple ng-touched" ng-if="to.key==null" oi-options="item for item in to.options" ng-model="model[options.key]" required="true" multiple="" id="formly_1_estoreMultiselect_category_0" name="formly_1_estoreMultiselect_category_0" formly-custom-validation="" ng-keyup="options.templateOptions['onKeyup'](model[options.key], options, this, $event)" ng-focus="options.templateOptions['onFocus'](model[options.key], options, this, $event)" ng-blur="options.templateOptions['onBlur'](model[options.key], options, this, $event)" type="estoreMultiselect" style="">
    <div class="select-search">
        <ul class="select-search-list">
            <!---->
            <li class="select-search-list-item select-search-list-item_input" ng-class="{'select-search-list-item_hide': inputHide}">
                <input autocomplete="off" ng-model="query" ng-keyup="keyUp($event)" ng-keydown="keyDown($event)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" placeholder="" style="">
            </li>
            <li class="select-search-list-item select-search-list-item_loader ng-hide" ng-show="showLoader">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="select-dropdown ng-hide" ng-show="isOpen">
    <!---->
    </div>
</oi-select>
```

This is the code I'm using to fetch it using Selenium WebDriver:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("formly_1_estoreMultiselect_category_0")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("formly_1_estoreMultiselect_category_0")).sendKeys("Networking");
```

And this is the Exception that is thrown:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: 
    Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
```

How can I add a value to `oi-select`?

Comment: Error is saying your element is not editable. And you can do sendkeys if its a input tag So try using xpath like `//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched']`

Comment: some how i am able to figure out how to send the value but its select field not input now the problem is after sending the value..based on that its doing LDAP search gives one value that option i have to select into the dropdown. its very easy if it is select field but mine is oi-select ...from the oi-select options how to pick the first values

Comment: can you share the URL if possible. If your option come after sending the text then Use below code. and again locate the very first element which is your expected

Answer (score 0):

Error is saying your "element is not editable" because you are sending text to a `div` while it should be an `input`

So here, to handle `io-select` tag element i have below reference code

```
public class Test {

    public static WebDriver driver;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Resources/chromedriver.exe"); 
        driver = new ChromeDriver();    
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://embed.plnkr.co/OYcetkAmDd21zhhToCC9/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.switchTo().frame(0).switchTo().frame(0);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid']")).sendKeys("boots");
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[contains(.,'boots')]")).click();

    }
}
```

So in your case your element would be `//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched']`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched']").sendKeys("yourText");
```

Comment: I have updated the example Code. Hope this will help you out for sure

Comment: i am trying with same code @Naren but its giving this exception org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched']

Comment: Hay Naren i tried bellow code     
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[12]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/span/ng-form/div[2]/ng-form/div[1]/span[1]/oi-select/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input")).sendKeys("Networking");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[12]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/span/ng-form/div[2]/ng-form/div[1]/span[1]/oi-select/div[1]/ul/li[contains(.,'Networking')]")).click();

Comment: i am able to send the data but i am not able to select the value in dropdown its showing Networking but while selecting its throwing exception like no such element..i am not sure what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use: http://embed.plnkr.co/OYcetkAmDd21zhhToCC9/ Plunker.

**Creating the class & constructor**

Let's first create a class for `OISelect` that accepts the locator of type `By` and the `WebDriver` object.

```
public class OISelect {

    By locator;
    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    public OISelect(By locator, WebDriver driver) {
        this.locator = locator;
        this.driver = driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
    }
}
```

**Creating helper functions**

We need to perform smaller functions like locating single and list of web elements:

```
/**
 * Return a web element
 * @param locator
 * @return
 */
private WebElement getWebElement(By locator) {
    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator)).get(0);
}

/**
 * Return a list of web elements
 * @param locator
 * @return
 */
private List<WebElement> getWebElements(By locator) {
    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator));
}

/**
 * Return the search input text box
 * @return
 */
private WebElement getSearchInputTextbox() {
    return getWebElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'select-search-list-item_input')]//input"));
}

/**
 * Return the list item matching option name
 * @param opionName
 * @return
 */
private WebElement getOption(String opionName) {
    return getWebElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'select-dropdown-optgroup-option')]"));
}
```

**Creating action performers**

Now we need to define the steps/actions that can be performed on the `oi-select` such as searching for an item name, selecting an item, verifying that results are displayed, verifying an item is selected, etc.

```
/**
 * Search an item name
 * 
 * @param itemName
 * @return
 */
public boolean searchItem(String itemName) {
    // Set text
    getSearchInputTextbox().sendKeys(itemName);
    // Verify text has been set
    boolean flag = getSearchInputTextbox().getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase(itemName);
    System.out.println("Search text has been set to " + itemName + "? " + flag);
    return flag;
}

/**
 * Select an item name
 * 
 * @param itemName
 * @return
 */
public boolean selectItem(String itemName) {
    if (hasResults()) {
        getOption(itemName).click();
    }
    return isSelected(itemName);
}

/**
 * Verify if an item name is selected
 * 
 * @param itemName
 * @return
 */
public boolean isSelected(String itemName) {
    boolean isSelected = false;
    // Get list of all selected items
    List<WebElement> allItems = getWebElements(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'select-search-list-item_selection')]"));
    // Iterate through each item to match expected item name
    for (WebElement item : allItems) {
        // Match item name 
        isSelected = item.getText().trim().contains(itemName);
        if (isSelected) {
            break; // Exit loop if matching item name exists
        }
    }
    System.out.println(itemName + " is selected? " + isSelected);
    return isSelected;
}

/**
 * Verify search results are displayed
 * 
 * @return
 */
public boolean hasResults() {
    boolean flag = getWebElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'select-dropdown') and not(contains(@class,'ng-hide'))]")) != null;
    System.out.println("Results are displayed? " + flag);
    return flag;
}
```

**Finally the main method to test all of the above**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Load driver and url
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String url = "http://embed.plnkr.co/OYcetkAmDd21zhhToCC9/";
    try {
        driver.get(url);
        WebElement frameElement = driver.findElement(By.className("plunker-space-iframe"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement).switchTo().frame("preview");

        // Select item
        OISelect select = new OISelect(By.tagName("oi-select"), driver);
        String itemName = "sneakers";
        select.searchItem(itemName);
        select.hasResults();
        select.selectItem(itemName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Zeeshan i tried the code still the same issue. i am using bellow code        driver.findElement(By.id("formly_1_input_title_0")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("formly_1_input_title_0")).sendKeys("RTool");
    driver.findElement(By.id("formly_1_input_toolName_1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("formly_1_input_toolName_1")).sendKeys("RTool");

Comment: while pointing to simple input fields i can fill the data but when it comes to OI-select By.id is not working so i am using xpath . the one you mentioned By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'select-search-list-item_input')]//input") this is giving no such element exception it somehow lookinh for the complete xpath

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[12]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/span/ng-form/div[2]/ng-form/div[1]/span[1]/oi-select/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input")).sendKeys("Networking");              this is working fine after passing the complete path of my div. after that i can see a value is filtered in the dropdown

Comment: to select that i am using driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[12]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/span/ng-form/div[2]/ng-form/div[1]/span[1]/oi-select/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input[contains(text(),'Networking')]")).click();    it thrown the same exception no such element found